# Youtube download link from http://www.youtube-mp3.org/

Tags: api, youtube, download, mp3

I've been using the http://www.youtube-mp3.org/ to obtain download links for mp3 songs for a "internet radio" project (download file stream and output it). Lately the http://www.youtube-mp3.org/ seemed to changed it's workflow. Till now I was able to obtain the proper format of the url:

http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?ab=128&video_id=KMU0tzLwhbE&h=5671e7d33d4eccb5b89ea8f54d9911d4&r=1387110278658.1527580295

Whereas r=timestamp 
I did the timestamp myself as epoch. This worked well without the .1527580295 suffix.
Unfortunetly this seems to be needed as the link without the suffix redirects back to the conversion site.

Up till now the algorithim was as mentioned:

[Youtube mp3 org linq acquiring explained](https://github.com/Kofel/yt_mp3/wiki/YouTube-MP3-API)

`http://www.youtube-mp3.org/api/itemInfo/?video_id=#{video_id}&ac=www&r=#{Time.now.to_i}`

Does any one know how to obtain the suffix part?

//Hey,
I'm not much of an web programming guy ... but this is something I have surely overlooked. Thanks!

Added this to my small C# API.

```
  <!-- language: c# -->
    const int AM = 65521;
    int GetCCSufix(string a)
    {            
        int c = 1, b = 0, d, e;
        var chars = a.ToCharArray();
        for(e =0; e< chars.Length; e ++)
        {
            d = chars[e];
            c = (c + d) % AM;
            b = (b + c) % AM;
        }
        return b << 16 | c;
    }
```

Works great ;)

Comment: Hi. I could not get it work. Can you share where you got the documentation of new API call? What do you send to the GetCCSufix as parameter? My result is; `r=1388806010725.1561527943?` which is the VideoID & The Unix Time as parameter to the GetCCSufix method. But does only work *some* times on service. Most I will receive blank page.

Comment: I mean, I use Java time, not Unix time. I think there is another issue on this service. Blank page error occurs on less watched videos only. But on website directly, it works always.

Comment: Hey,
Sorry for the great delay in anwsering -> New year leisure I guess. I'll answer it when I'll be back home.

Comment: Can you give an example link to verify that the blank page occurs? They have to convert it first and probably then it's cached. But if it happens after that then it is odd.

Comment: I think's its not allowed here. can you catch my by email to info on my goldengel.ch website?

Comment: Any idea on how to deal with the new version of the API? @Nasenbaer

Comment: No. It simple does not work at all. I created own service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what this suffix means but reading the client javascript file from youtube-mp3.org you can learn how to generate it.

```
var __AM=65521; // the largest prime less than 2^16...
function cc(a){
    var c = 1, b = 0, d, e;
    for(e = 0; e < a.length; e++){
        d = a.charCodeAt(e);
        c = (c+d)%__AM;
        b = (b+c)%__AM;
    }
    return b<<16|c;
}
```

The generated media URL is :

```
"http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?ab=128&video_id="+video_id+"&h="+info.h+"&r="+timeNow+"."+cc(video_id+timeNow)
```

with

```
var timeNow = Date.now().toString();
```

Comment: This is awesome! I spent weeks on this! Thank you so much!

Comment: My friend this url is deprecated. A new argument added at the end of the url. Please update your answer.

Comment: @Raphaël Could you update your answer for the new version of the API?

Comment: Why not use youtubeinmp3.com/api - it has an official API. The only downside is that every few downloads they will redirect you to their website before starting the download... (but it's not the case if you do your homework good... ;)).

Comment: I just found youtubeinmp3.com has a daily download limit... :\